# Reversing a struct in undocumented API

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm reading through a book describing reversing techniques and I was confused.

```
    RtlNumberGenericTableElements:
7C923FD2 PUSH EBP
7C923FD3 MOV EBP,ESP
7C923FD5 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [EBP+8]
7C923FD8 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [EAX+14]
7C923FDB POP EBP
7C923FDC RET 4
```

basically [EBP+8] contains the address of a generic table struct, and we're moving the value of the 6th element of the struct to EAX then return it.
In the book, the author translated the struct to C and concluded that this value moved to EAX is nothing but the number of elements in the table.

```
struct TABLE
{
    UNKNOWN Member1;
    UNKNOWN_PTR Member2;
    UNKNOWN_PTR Member3;
    UNKNOWN_PTR Member4;
    UNKNOWN Member5;
    ULONG NumberOfElements;
    UNKNOWN Member7;
    UNKNOWN Member8;
    UNKNOWN Member9;
    UNKNOWN Member10;
};
```

The thing that confused me is to see the ULONG datatype, so it's refering to a 64bit value right?

And I forgot to mention that when the struct was initialized in a previous snippets of disassembly all the elements were 4 byte long.

Comment: ULONGs (in Windows) are typically 32 bit unsigned ints.

Comment: Once upon a time what we considered long were things which were not so very long, long ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `ULONG` is 32-bits wide:

> ULONG: An unsigned LONG. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.
>   This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows: typedef unsigned long
>   ULONG;

The author gets to that conclusion since the assembly instruction is moving a `DWORD`, which is 32-bits wide as well.